# How to create SAM Template for CloudFront and AWS API Gateway WebSocket

Tags: websocket, amazon-cloudfront

I am struggling to find documentations, procedures, and examples on how to create SAM Template for CloudFront and AWS API Gateway WebSocket.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a sample AWS SAM template for the Lambda application from the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html. Copy the text below to a file and save it next to the ZIP package you created previously. Note that the `Handler` and `Runtime` parameter values should match the ones you used when you created the function in the previous section.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  LambdaFunctionOverHttps:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
  Handler: index.handler
  Runtime: nodejs12.x
  Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
  Events:
    HttpPost:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: '/DynamoDBOperations/DynamoDBManager'
        Method: post
```